# UPDATED COM JOIN

Tags: tabela-banco-de-dados, mysql

Preciso atualizar algumas strings em uma tabela e fazer o join em outra coluna de uma outra tabela, estou usando esse script:

```
UPDATE funcionario f
    join usuario u  on f.id_funcionario = u.ID_USUARIO
    SET f.email = REPLACE ( f.email , 'group.com.br' , 'group.com' )
    where u.login in (-- "LISTA DE LOGINS" )
```

Me retorna esse erro:

[erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nyx0b.png)

Comment: Pela descrição do erro, o safe_mode está ativado. Você pode desativar seguindo este exemplo https://gist.github.com/stormwild/5746860

Answer (score 0):

update
funcionario f
set
f.email = replace ( f.email ,
'group.com.br' ,
'group.com' )
where
f.id_funcionario in (
select
id_funcionario
from
funcionario f
join usuario u on
f.id_funcionario = u.ID_USUARIO
where
u.login in (/ lista de logins /))

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).